# save DenseMatrix Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

what is the best method to save DenseMatrix object? I have create next piece of the code (two possibilities to save as String and as Array):

```
public void saveToData() throws FileNotFoundException{
    String bm = BinaryMatrix.toString();
    double[] arr = BinaryMatrix.toArray();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/home/user/filename.txt");
    PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter("/home/user/filename_bin.txt");
    out.print(bm);
    for(Double x : arr){
        out1.println(x);
    }
    out.close();
    out1.close();
}
```

In this case I have a cuted output (not the whole matrix is going to be saved). What is the best possibility to save the DenseMatrix object in Java?

Comment: That is saving the string representation of the object, probably not the object itself.

Comment: thank you a lot, I also havbe found another solution with toArray() method, where I get an array back...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe opinion based answer. But, you should save it into a `CSV` file. Whole approach seems wrong.

I.e. I was having an opportunity to use [la4j](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j) API to perform operations with matrices. You can basically populate matrix fairly easy, read matrix row by row, convert each row to CSV formatted string and write into `CSV` file .

Comment: ok, thank you. For me csv is perfect. But this is a DenseMatrix from the Spark library, I wnat to have it as Matrix object of Spark...